# Как прикрутить callback к window.open?

Tags: javascript, oauth

Суть - вызвать функцию, открывающую окно, и после отработки скрипта в окне после его закрытия, передать данные обратно в функцию, т.е. вызвать callback с параметрами.
Так работает окно "войти через vk|fb|mr".
Есть цель - сделать такое же через twitter и odnoklassniki, но, насколько я помню, у них нет своего дружественного JS API для этого.

Да, я пробежался по нативным либам от vk и mr, но ничего внятного не нашёл, а код от fb сильно сжат и нечитаем в принципе, как механизм работает - самому разобраться видимо не судьба.

Comment: Вам нужно отследить закрытие окна?

Comment: Нет. Нужно при открытии, передать функцию, которую новое окно вызовет перед закрытием с какими-то параметрами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто

```
opener.myCallBackFunction(parameters); window.close()
```

вызовет функцию родителя и закроет новое окно.